# let $f(x) = \tan ^{-1}x, x \in \mathbb{R} $ .then choose the correct statement

Tags: real-analysis

let $f(x) = \tan ^{-1}x, x \in \mathbb{R} $ .then

choose the  correct statement

$1.$  there  exist a   polynomial  $p(x)$  satisfying  $p(x)f'(x) =1$ for all $x$

$2.$$f^{(n)}(0) =0$ for all positive  even integer  $n$

$3.$ the  sequence $\{f^{(n)} (0)  \}$ is  unbounded

$4.$$f^{(n)} (0)  =0$ for all $n$

My attempt : if $ x =0$ ,then  obviously  $f(x) =0$ because $\tan 0 =0$

from this  i see option  $2)$  and option $4)$  will correct

other option   i don't know...

Any hints/solution will be apprecaited

thanks u

Comment: For $(2)$ and $(4)$, I think you misunderstood $f^{(n)}(0)$ as $(f(0))^n; f^{(n)}(0)$ means the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f$ at $x=0$.

Comment: thanks @ShubhamJohri...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to 1, viz. $p=1+x^2$. Yes to 2, because $f$, like $\tan x$, is odd and infinitely differentiable. But 4 is false, viz. e.g. $n=1$. As for 3, note that $f=x-x^3/3+x^5/5-\cdots$, so the odd derivaties at $0$ are $(-1)^n(2n)!$, so 3 is true.

Comment: @J. G im not  getting  how  option 3, 4 false   can u elaborate  more  in detail ???

Comment: @BarryCipra Sorry; I misread it as restricting to even $n$.

Comment: THanks u @JG ..